# How to output a warning message to the user in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently uploading a CSV file with values during the APEX data load wizard into below table. The trigger runs before each update on Table1 but struggling to display the htp output to the user. Anyone know how to do this in APEX?

### Table 1 (CSV)

**Mobile**,**Address**,**Product**,**comments**

12312131,50 long street,Product1,null

1231231,14 blah place,Product2,comment4

### Trigger

```
create or replace trigger "TABLE1_T1"
BEFORE
 update on "TABLE1"
 for each row
  begin

    if :old.comments is not null then
     htp.prn ('Warning: ' || :new.comments || ' will replace ' ||    
     :old.comments);
    end if;
  end;
```

Comment: You're probably better off uploading the CSV data to a temp holding table, then creating a post-upload process to run your validations and then do the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can not print a message from a trigger. You can do a validation but this will be more like a error and not a warning so you can't continue the process.

Or you can add a dynamic action on `before page submit` that will popup a confirm msg and if user presses `OK` the process will continue.

Comment: thanks for that. How would you do this? I've just tried and failed. Been googling crazy for this

Answer (score 0):

You could try using APEX_ERROR

```
begin
 if :old.comments is not null then
   APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR (
   p_message          => 'Warning: ' || :new.comments || ' will replace ' ||    
         :old.comments',
   p_additional_info  => SQLERRM,
   p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification);
  end if;
end;
```

from https://docs.oracle.com/html/E28475_02/apex_error.htm

Comment: Thanks but where exactly would I add in the dataload pages?  Would I need to create a new region on last Page and a classic report and paste it there?